# Why doesn't my hello world driver module print anything?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm very new to kernel module programming and right now I'm trying to run the most basic hello world module program, however I could not get any output.

I have written the hello world program introduced in Linux Device Drivers 3rd ed and got some help from [this website](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c147.htm) and [this one](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN119).

**hello.c**

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int hello_init(void){
    printk("<1>Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, world..\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

The file is in `/home/volkan/drive` directory. Along with the c file, I have my Makefile

**Makefile**

```
obj-m += hello.o
```

From the terminal, I execute this command for compiling the module:

```
sudo make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build M=/home/volkan/drive/ modules
```

Resulting in:

```
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/volkan/drive/hello.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/volkan/drive/hello.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/volkan/drive/hello.ko
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
```

I assume up to this point, nothing went wrong. Now, I insert my module and then remove:

```
volkan@Varaquilex ~/drive $ sudo insmod ./hello.ko
volkan@Varaquilex ~/drive $ sudo rmmod hello
volkan@Varaquilex ~/drive $
```

There is no output. I also have little experience in linux, so explanatory answers are more than welcome. Am I doing something wrong? Why cannot I see any output?

Comment: Do you have any output in `dmesg`?

Comment: When I `cat dmesg` I see lots of stuff, but nothing related to the module. I assume it should be in the end of file but not only its not in the end, its not in the middle or beginning either.

Comment: However, `cat kern.log` did the trick: 
`
Dec  9 18:42:46 Varaquilex kernel: [ 2314.937815] <1>Hello, world!
Dec  9 18:42:49 Varaquilex kernel: [ 2317.873400] Goodbye, world..
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kernel messages are logged in the `kern.log` file located in `/var/log`. Depending on your system, it may also be in `dmesg`. So you have to `cat` accordingly.

Use the command `cat /var/log/kern.log`

```
Dec  9 18:51:10 Varaquilex kernel: [ 2818.079572] <1>Hello, world!
Dec  9 18:55:02 Varaquilex kernel: [ 3050.256134] Goodbye, world..
```

Comment: Note they aren't *necessarily* there; this is determined in `/etc/syslog.conf` (but look for  `/etc/rsyslog.conf` first, that will take precedence if it exists).  You'll find some reference to `kern.log` in that file.   You'll also notice the priorities (1 = alert, etc) are used there.  Strange this didn't end up in `dmesg` tho.

Comment: Hmmm -- notice `<1>Hello, world!`.  Methinks the API has changed a bit since your reference was written, and that's perhaps not being processed as a priority, so the default is used.  Something to investigate, anyway.

Comment: I looked up `rsyslog.conf`. Nothing related to `kern.log` there. When I search for `kern` there is only 1 line that has a match: `$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support`. Perhaps this is the reference to `kern.log` file?

Comment: Maybe, although the directives should still be directives;  it could be that `imklog` includes its own defaults (although the same module is used here, but I have no `/var/log/kern.log`...). There's probably also an `/etc/rsyslog.d/` directory with stuff included by `rsyslog.conf`; those files may or may not contain much.

Comment: Also possible: your system isn't actually using `rsyslogd` -- try `ps -A | grep syslog`, you'll get either `syslogd` or `rsyslogd`.  They use different conf files (hence `/etc/syslog.conf`).